# Visual Studio Crashes every time a project is opened

Tags: visual-studio, multi-device-hybrid-apps

This happens with both TypeScript and JavaScript projects.
I am using Visual Studio Premium 2013 with Update 2

What Happens:

- I create or open an existing Multi-Device project
- I press 'Cancel' on the Windows 8.1 developer License dialog box
- The project loads and I can see the files
- Visual Studio crashes

Here is the crash log from Event Viewer

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

I have re-installed and repaired the tools a few times, but to no avail.
It is strange because I have it working at home (with Ultimate), but not at work. I also have all the third party applications needed installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

### UPDATE

After doing some testing at home, I believe the issue may be being caused by the Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators. They were not installed on my machine at home, and I could load up projects without crashing, but after installing them, Visual Studio started crashing. Furthermore, I have tried uninstalling the emulators, projects still crash, but not as frequently. Hope this helps in any way.

Comment: What about if you don't cancel the W8.1 licence dialog, but if you complete the registration process (which is free unless you want to publish apps)

Comment: @SteveB OK, I will give it a go. Just have to clear it with my boss.

Comment: @SteveB I have signed up for the license and accepted the dialog, but it still crashes. Thanks for suggestion though :)

Comment: Regarding your update, can you try to disable the Hyper-V role on your computer? (beware of potential virtual machine loss)

Comment: @SteveB aha! This seems to have helped. Whilst Visual Studio still crashes, If I create a Javascript project, then go to File -> Recent Projects and Solutions, and load up the Hybrid project, Visual Studio does not crash. This did not work when Hyper-V was installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was slightly different but in my case VS crashed with this project template due to a specific Web Essentials version (https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1238). After updating to te latest (nightly) build VS stopped crashing while loading a Multi Device Hybrid App project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: VS2013, Update2 was crashing when I created a new Multi-Device Hybrid App or if I opened an existing one.

What resolved this for me was to de-install Web Essentials and install the latest web essentials per the instructions here: http://vswebessentials.com/download